# Using celery and amqp to retrieve processing results from a remote server?

Tags: json, django, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

A little bit of background. I have two boxes - the first box A runs Django, Postgres and Celery to run some tasks async in the background. Box A connects to Box B running the RabbitMQ broker and the data processing workers consuming tasks sent by Celery onto the queues (although this may be moved off to other machines at a later point).

Celery is working quite well to send tasking onto the remote broker and I am also using the same RabbitMQ broker to retrieve processing results (text or JSON) once the task has completed.

```
  app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp://broker', broker='amqp://username:password@broker/')
```

My question is whether this is good practice and whether it will scale? The JSON/text results will be 20K-2MB.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No one can answer this for you - it depends on the specifics of your application, network etc etc.

If you have some idea of your anticipated traffic/workload then you can do some back-of-the-envelope calculations to get a rough idea of what kind of requirements you will need.

e.g. if you can expect to have 10,000 concurrent requests then you will need max 2MB * 10,000 = 10GB RAM for redis, plus network connectivity to match the expected throughput.